# Stack Exchange Signal processing in the real life: meeting contributors

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

*[On  meeting "Stack Exchange Signal processing" contributors]*

**Current answers:**

- Finland, Hämeenlinna, [Olli Niemitalo](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/users/15347/olli-niemitalo)
- France, Greater Paris area (Nanterre), [Laurent Duval](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/users/15892/laurent-duval)
- The Netherlands, Eindhoven area, [Matt L.](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4298/matt-l)
- United Kingdom (South Wales), [A_A](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1212/a-a?tab=profile)
- USA, Connecticut, Hartford to Boston, [Peter K.](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/users/80/peter-k)
- USA, Massachusetts, Boston and the North Shore, [Dan Boschen](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/users/21048/dan-boschen)

**Current question:**

We have been:

- writing questions and answers,
- commenting each other,
- editing posts, having arguments sometimes,
- been down- or up-voters.

Some of you folks have entered my sphere of consciousness.  In other virtual networks, I have met some contacts, 99.9% of the time with a lot of pleasure (only one outlier). I even go on vacations, regularly chat or occasionally have lunch  with a dozen  of them. Long-lasting virtual contacts sometimes abolish IRL social barriers.

I dwell in the suburbs of Paris, France, and I would be glad meeting, sharing a glass or a coffee with any SE.DSP contributor, either in transit or sedentary in the capital of France.

**Would  some of you feel interested in meeting some of your SE.DSPeers, when they are close by? Each from his/her location?**

[EDIT] If your answer is positive, I propose to open the answer by a mention of you approximative location (plus a radius of action).

Comment: Proposal: Make a community wiki answer for things like upcoming DSP events/conferences. Why not meet around DySPAN, FOSDEM, 34c3, MWC, GRCon, ISWCS, siggraph, some SPIE conf/exhib… if you're in the area anyway, even if not attending said event?

Comment: Good idea. I am trying to maintain, on my sparse time (negative), such a list of events http://www.laurent-duval.eu/siva-conferences.html

Comment: That list is 60 dBAwesome!

Comment: I hope I can make it more professional some days: real web langugae, online updates suggestions, etc.

Comment: I like @MarcusMüller's idea of a wiki for upcoming events we're attending. What I dislike most about the SE network is that sometimes it feels like a straitjacket, in that it disfavors informal conversation and peer relationships.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome to **Hämeenlinna, Finland**.

I've met with two on-line friends from music-dsp circles. It was great both times, had pizza with the first one (I bicycled to Sweden where we met) and beer with the second one (Norwegian, he had business in Oulu where I lived at the time).

EDIT:
[image: Nimsaad & Olli Niemitalo]
*Users MimSaad (left) and Olli Niemitalo (right) in Oulu, 5 September 2017.*

Comment: I have a Nordic metabolism. Should go back to Finland some day (only been in Helsinki once in 1999)

Comment: @LaurentDuval Bring your T-shirt for a photo :-)

Comment: I will. Same in Paris 4U

Comment: When I entered engineering school (long ago), I discovered both computers and internet. My first downloads (wais, ftp) came from Finnish universities. 5 Mb, a few hours. Metal chords and lyrics. Finnish univ. were far ahead French universities, and among the first in Europe.

Comment: whoa, 539 km??  i didn't know Finland was that big.  are you above the Arctic circle??  (now i'll have to look it up.)

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson The Arctic Circle is about 200 km north from Oulu.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo , Hey that's me! hooray!

Comment: Excellent, was it the first SE.DSP meeting?

Comment: @LaurentDuval seems like it may have been! :)

Comment: Looks fun! Definitely should go visit the Nordic countries.

Comment: Great stuff! :-)

Comment: Hmm, the guy on the right may be an impostor... _no feather_.

Answer (score 7):

I also think it could be fun meeting some SE.DSPers IRL if our space-time paths can be made to intersect with little effort. I can usually be found in the **Eindhoven area, the Netherlands**.

Answer (score 6):

**Welcome to [West Hartford, Connecticut, USA.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Hartford,_Connecticut)**

Laurent, [I'm a dinosaur](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!search/comp.dsp$20kootsookos$20before$3A1992$2F01$2F01/comp.dsp/BgeLwykHTcs/21x-RQgiNWYJ) from the <kbd>comp.dsp</kbd> usenet news days (though comp.dsp is still going, I find!).  I made several online friends through there, and they've propagated to here, Facebook, and Twitter.

A few months ago, I was happy to meet up with two <kbd>comp.dsp</kbd>ers up in Boston (two hours drive from me). One I'd met IRL a couple of times before, and the other I'd never met even though we'd known each other online for 15+ years.  It ended up being a pretty big geek-out over beers and pizza. :-)

It's always been a pleasure; I can't recall any outliers, though I dare say there could be some.

Yes, I do feel relatively safe about such meetings.

Comment: I've spent a joyful 4-month in Boston during my PhD, long-long ago...

Comment: geepers, Peter, i didn't know you preceded me at **comp.dsp**.  (and what's with this <kbd>kbd</kbd> html tag?  hadn't known of it before.  what's it for?)

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I think it's to make text look like tags. I just wanted to highlight comp.dsp using it.

Comment: Olli Niemitalo and MimSaad did the first IRL meeting. Do you mind if I tick Olli's answer?

Comment: @LaurentDuval Great! Of course not! Feel free! :-)

Answer (score 6):

**[Nanterre, a former central celt city of Gaul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanterre#Name), before and close to Paris, France ($\pm$ 30 kms)**

SE.DSPeers (the double "e" is on purpose) of all countries unite. I have a network of signal/image processing folks here. And know of a few nice bars and restaurants, with diverse types of foods and drinks.

Comment: Laurent, I lived 4 years in Paris; I did my PhD at ENST (now Telecom ParisTech). I miss it!

Comment: Underground network :-)?

Comment: @Royi Underground only when it rains or it's smoggy.

Comment: History says underground network of French always fought for the right side and done amazing things :-).

Comment: I wished it were "always" on the bright side. Not so sure, let's hope that was the majority though

Answer (score 5):

Hello from the **United Kingdom (South Wales)**.

Great idea. I was under the impression that the majority of the board was from the US, purely based on the timings of the answers. In fact, one occurrence was a pure ["Goodmorning"](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/45212/best-way-to-process-this-signal/) :)

Finland, France & The Netherlands are pretty close too.

I wonder if a meetup could be triggered in the greater area of an event we might all be attending (?) (e.g. a conference).

Comment: A conference get-together is a great idea.  The old usenet comp.dsp group held a couple of IRL conferences in [2004](https://www.danvillesignal.com/customer-support-dsp-developer-resources/comp.dsp-conference/) and [2010](http://compdsp.com/).

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to **Boston, Massachusetts** and the **North Shore**!

Yes love the idea and welcome any fellow "SE.DSPeers" (with the double E as Laurent notated) for a beer, coffee, etc when in the Boston Massachusetts USA area, when space-time paths can easily intersect as MattL described.

Comment: when Peter K comes up here from Insurance City to visit, again, we can get together somewhere.  if it's a Saturday, i know of some good live Irish music with no cover (but the booze ain't cheap).

Comment: and, Dan, you and i can meet anytime you wish.

Comment: Super, great idea

Comment: Sounds like a plan! Must try something over the summer.

Comment: Did a portion of my PhD at Boston University. Great memories from there